# How to store files from a website in the user's cache?

Tags: javascript, php, file, web, browser-cache

I'm looking for methods to store big files (up to multiple GB) without the files can be tapped by common means.

That means, that the currently being downloaded file should not appear in the browser's download list.

Is there any way that supports all modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, maybe Edge?).

Here's an example that only works with small files: https://mega.nz/#!f9gDjJhK!4PrH8CcATtDHU3Rw1eSX_ZCJGV99jmckOZAgJJOvq54

For large files, MEGA requests the permission to save files locally. So in Chrome I have to allow "Auto-Downloads".

Would be glad if anyone could show me how to do, whether with PHP, JS or else.

Comment: It would be quite ludicrous to allow any random website to store multiple gigabytes on a random visitor's hard disk without so much as a confirmation…

Comment: For sure, but at completion the file should be moved into the download folder. Also a permission requirement for storing big files is no problem.